# Binary semaphore for process syncronization

Tags: c++, linux, synchronization, semaphore, producer-consumer

I want synchronize between producer and consumer processes. I use a cyclic buffer without mutexes or semaphores.
This solution allows me to avoid waiting on synchronization.
I use shared memory cyclic buffer for the data sharing.

Now I want to allow the consumer process to sleep while the producer doesn't produce new data.
Regular named semaphore doesn't make the job for me, because it has an integer value. I need some binary semaphore, that is not incrementing, but just signals the consumer whether there is a new data or not.
I.e. the produced should not increment the semaphore value, but just to set it to 1.

I write in C++ for Linux OS

Comment: Why not have the number of elements in the semaphore? Producer increments the value on insert, consumer decrements the value when processed.

Comment: What have you written so far in c++?

Comment: If you have shared memory, why not put a ```pthread_mutex_t``` and a ```pthread_cond_t``` in that memory? Make sure to set the ```pshared``` attribute on construction

Comment: Thanks, mch, for the comment.
I did as his advice, using semaphore to count the elements in the queue.
This solved the issue for me, and I didn't continue to investigate.